# "Undefined index: media" when I want upload a media with Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I use TwitterOauth, a Abraham Williams library for Twitter API.

I want upload a media to insert into Direct Message.

I've an error when I try to upload base64 encode PNG image, with chunked, or not.

```
$upload = $connection->upload('media/upload', [
    'media_data' => $base64Encoded,
    'media_type' => 'image/png',
], true); // chunked

dd($upload);
```

Some people talk about passing media_data to media and giving the path to the file, but the Twitter API allows to give base64 encoded media, so I'm trying to make it work because I don't want to transfer the media to the server before uploading it to Twitter, even temporarily, because I don't have write access to the server.

So I generate a base64 image, and I just want to upload it to Twitter via the API and TwitterOauth SDK.

The image is generated with PHP, I encode it in base64. I want to upload directly to the Twitter API without saving the image. Twitter API allows this with the media_data parameter, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Here, the error I have when I execute the script.

[image]

**How I can upload media from Twitter API?**

Comment: I think, in https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/main/src/TwitterOAuth.php#L367, the parameters variable use media instead media_data.

Comment: And what's your question about this? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried lot of solutions found on Google. Some people talk about passing media_data to media and giving the path to the file, but the Twitter API allows to give base64 encoded media, so I'm trying to make it work because I don't want to transfer the media to the server even temporarily.

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to transfer the media to the server"? Please add all clarification to your question by editing

Comment: I still don't get the problem: if you already generated the image **on the server**, you have all information there. Or which is "the server" that has generated the image, but you don't want to tranfer the image to?

Comment: @NicoHaase The image is generated with PHP, I encode it in base64. I want to upload directly to the Twitter API without saving the image. Twitter API allows this with the media_data parameter, but I can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: The location @pirmax linked to appears to be the only one where this library uses the `media_data` parameter - but it _fills_ that itself, by reading chunks from the _file_ it opens via `fopen($parameters['media'], 'rb')`. You could perhaps get this done, if you write your image data (the real one, not base64 encoded, the library does that itself with the read chunks) into `php://memory` first, and then try to pass that for the parameter `media`, so that the library will open that stream and read the data from there. https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/issues/681, that problem is worked on since some years, but without any progress. If the library does not support reading from a raw string yet, you should either write your raw string to a file (because reading data from a file to upload that data **is** supported), or you could work on that ticket to get it done within the library.

That's the beauty of open source: if a library does not support your needs, you can extend it and make others happy that might have the same problem :)